# toArray(T[]) method in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

When I was going through ArrayList implementation, I found a weird piece of code in toArray(T[]) method.

```
 public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        if (a.length < size)
            // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
            return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
        System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
        if (a.length > size)
            a[size] = null;
        return a;
    }
```

The part is,

```
 if (a.length > size)
    a[size] = null;
```

why only the element at this index in the array is set to null? Once the array is filled with the contents of the list, the elements at the remaining indices should have been set to null, right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I believe it is so that you can look through the items and stop when you hit `null`, but it's not foolproof (since your items might legitimately contain `null`).

Comment: 99.9% of the time you don't care what remaining items are. And if you do you can fill them with nulls youself. Avoiding pointless performance overhead is the key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29) explains why:

> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in the array immediately following the end of the list is set to `null`. **(This is useful in determining the length of the list only if the caller knows that the list does not contain any `null` elements.)**